# AWS Glue shuffles columns when writing to Snowflake

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aws-glue

When writing a dynamic frame from AWS Glue to an existing Snowflake table, my data gets shuffled into other columns.

For example:
Writing this dataframe with the code below...

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | b1 | c1 |
| a2 | b2 | c2 |

… could look like …

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| b1 | c1 | a1 |
| b2 | c2 | a2 |

… after writing.

Code:

```
snowflake_table_result = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame=dataframe,
    connection_type="snowflake",
    connection_options={
        "autopushdown": "on",
        "dbtable": "TABLE",
        "preactions": f"DELETE FROM DB.SCHEMA.TABLE WHERE data = 'old';",
        "connectionName": "Snowflake connection",
        "sfDatabase": f"DB",
        "sfSchema": "SCHEMA"
    }
)
```

Is there some argument I am missing or a key part of the documentation?

Comment: Do you have mapping defined in AWS Glue for the Snowflake table?

Comment: @Sergiu: I have a table which has the exact same names as the Snowflake table. Do I need a more specific mapping than that?

Comment: When you write from AWS Glue to Snowflake a COPY INTO operation is triggered automatically. I would go in Snowflake UI at Query History and verify how the COPY INTO looks like. It is the first time when I hear the data is shifted. Are you able to display the dataframe before it's written to Snowflake? And where do you get the source data from?

Comment: Before writing the data to Snowflake it is written into Glue Catalog. For comparison I queried the data with Athena and compared a few columns for the same rows (Need to mention: row_id and a few other columns are not shifted): There is definitely a shift. Between Athena and Snowflake I only do data.select(*[col(c).alias(c.upper()) for c in data.columns]) before wrapping the dataframe into a DynamicFrame again.